# how can you delete a sound file in java?

Tags: java, file

I have a sound file that's recorded in my Java code and I need some code to delete it.

Comment: have a look into the java io api?

Comment: What's special about a "sound file"?  Have you looked at the javadocs for `java.io.File`?

Comment: Could you show the code that records and saves the sound?

Comment: Completely and utterly impossible to answer without knowing what you're doing or seeing your code.

Comment: ive found all this code online already! im using jarnal and have added code to allow a play, record and stop button within the toolbar. after i record a sound it creates a sound file that i want to have deleted within my code later on otherwise i'll have multiple sound files built up when i keep recording. any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

**What is so special about sound file??!!!**

You can use this code.

```
public static void deleteFile(String file){
    File myFile = new File(file);

    if (!myFile.delete()){
     System.out.println("Deletion was not sucessful");
    }else{
      System.out.println("File deleted");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the answer is *so* obvious (`file.delete()`), I suspect that you're *actually* having issues with deleting it. I.e, `file.delete()` has returned `false` and the file is in reality not been deleted from the disk file system.

In that case, you can not delete it when you still have pointers open on that file. For example, when you have a `InputStream` or `OutputStream` on the file in your Java code, then you will not be able to delete the file as long as you do not call `close()` on the streams.

So, to fix that issue, you need to ensure that you call `close()` on any `InputStream` and `OutputStream` in the `finally` block of the `try` block where you're using the streams.

E.g.

```
File file = new File(name);
OutputStream output = null;

try {
    output = new FileOutputStream(file);
    // Write to output here ...

    file.delete(); // Will always fail because output is not closed.
} finally {
    if (output != null) try { output.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
}

file.delete(); // Will succeed after close of output.
```